# .NET 7.0 MVC Sending View to Controller Custom List Object

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I send the list information I took from the Web API to the Web Page as a list via the Controller. Here I show the elements I need. I want to bulk delete the items I selected as checkboxes from these displayed elements. The relevant function falls on the Controller, but the parameter is empty.

**This is where I send my list from controls to view.**

```
try
{
    List<Material> MaterialInfo = new List<Material>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Materials");
        if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var MaterialsResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            MaterialInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Material>>(MaterialsResponse);
            CurrentMaterials.Add(MaterialInfo);
        }
        return View(MaterialInfo);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return View();
}
```

**In this section, the response from the View in the Controller is entered here, but the Incoming List materials section appears empty. I tried changing this to List obj and object obj but it still doesn't work.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StartProcedure(List<Material> materials)
{
    try
    {
        //foreach (var item in materials)
        //{

        //}
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**This part is the parameters that I show on the screen in View.**

```
<tbody>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("StartProcedure", "LastedStatus", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @foreach (var material in Model)
        {
            @if(material.CabinStatus == CabinStatus.outCabin)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => material.isSelected, new { @class = "checkbox" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.Code)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.BatchNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.RfId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.Weight)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.MaterialDrawerNo)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.MaterialLocation_X)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.MaterialLocation_Y)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.RemainingTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.PickUpTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.OutsideTime)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.CabinStatus)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.TimeAlarm)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.LifeEnding)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => material.TimeProcess)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

        <input type="button" id="deleteItems" value="Delete Selected Items" name="Verify Order Information" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" />
    }
    
    
</tbody>
```

**The action performed when the Delete button is pressed in this section.**

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("body").on("click", "#deleteItems", function () {
            //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
            var materials = new Array();
            $("#table BODY TR").each(function () {
                var row = $(this);
                var material = {};
                material.isSelected = row.find("td:eq(0)").html();
                material.Id = row.find("td:eq(1)").html();
                material.Code = row.find("td:eq(2)").html();
                material.Name = row.find("td:eq(3)").html();
                material.Description = row.find("td:eq(4)").html();
                material.BatchNumber = row.find("td:eq(5)").html();
                material.RfId = row.find("td:eq(6)").html();
                material.Weight = row.find("td:eq(7)").html();
                material.MaterialDrawerNo = row.find("td:eq(8)").html();
                material.MaterialLocation_X = row.find("td:eq(9)").html();
                material.MaterialLocation_Y = row.find("td:eq(10)").html();
                material.RemainingTime = row.find("td:eq(0)").html();
                material.PickUpTime = row.find("td:eq(11)").html();
                material.OutsideTime = row.find("td:eq(12)").html();
                material.CabinStatus = row.find("td:eq(13)").html();
                material.TimeAlarm = row.find("td:eq(14)").html();
                material.LifeEnding = row.find("td:eq(15)").html();
                material.TimeProcess = row.find("td:eq(16)").html();

                materials.push(material);
            });

            //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/LastedStatus/StartProcedure",
                data: JSON.stringify(materials),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " Success.");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**In this section, the part of the operation that is performed when the Delete button is pressed is the part that I tried before.**

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("body").on("click", "#deleteItems", function () {
            //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
            var materials = new Array();
            $("#table BODY TR").each(function () {
                var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                var material = {};
                material.isSelected = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                material.Id = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                material.Code = row.find("TD").eq(2).html();
                material.Name = row.find("TD").eq(3).html();
                material.Description = row.find("TD").eq(4).html();
                material.BatchNumber = row.find("TD").eq(5).html();
                material.RfId = row.find("TD").eq(6).html();
                material.Weight = row.find("TD").eq(7).html();
                material.MaterialDrawerNo = row.find("TD").eq(8).html();
                material.MaterialLocation_X = row.find("TD").eq(9).html();
                material.MaterialLocation_Y = row.find("TD").eq(10).html();
                material.RemainingTime = row.find("TD").eq(11).html();
                material.PickUpTime = row.find("TD").eq(12).html();
                material.OutsideTime = row.find("TD").eq(13).html();
                material.CabinStatus = row.find("TD").eq(14).html();
                material.TimeAlarm = row.find("TD").eq(15).html();
                material.LifeEnding = row.find("TD").eq(16).html();
                material.TimeProcess = row.find("TD").eq(17).html();

                materials.push(material);
            });

            //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/LastedStatus/StartProcedure2",
                data: JSON.stringify(materials),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + " Success.");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: did you control for your material and materials variables with console.log? To solve the problem, it might be best to first see what is assigned to them.

Comment: Where is your controller code? Also I cannot see any code related to delete operation.

Comment: @thejrprogrammer I'm not good with the web. I developed a desktop software and web interface support was requested, so I had to log in to the web side. I don't know how to do what you say.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I also added the Controller section.

Comment: if you use like the code below: 'console.log('material ',material,' materials ',materials);' in the last line of javascript code. When you run the web app, press f12 or right click and inspect, then you can see the values at the console tab. Or add a breakpoint to your controller code and run the project with debug to check what comes in the materials.

Comment: @thejrprogrammer jquery.min.js:2 POST 192.168.1.50:5268/LastedStatus/StartProcedure 500 (Internal Server Error) try { r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null) } catch (e) { if (o) throw e } It gives an error here.

Comment: Can you see the StartProcedure request in the Network tab? If you can see it, can you click on it and check the payload? The format of the data may not be as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to bulk delete the items I selected as checkboxes from these
> displayed elements. The relevant function falls on the Controller, but
> the parameter is empty.

Well, based on your scenario and description along with the shared code snippet , I have tried to reproduce your issue and I ened up with 3 findings which causing null list in controller and into `var materials = new Array();`

Let's have a look in practice, I have investigated the issue step by step.

Incorrect Script:

First of all, I have run eactly same code with yours and I founded there is http/https issue while loading your issue which is as following:

[image]

Inconsistent Table Element Definition:

Apart from that, you are extracting your table element by `table BODY TR` but I haven't seen any table and tableId within your code. So when you would be iterating using this way, it cannot find your data and therefore, would failed to bind data into your array. and that causing null array on submit. As you can see below:

[image]

[image]

Missing Request Body In Controller:

You are sending json object from your ajax request from request body but your controller request ignorant about it, and you are certainly missing `[FromBody]` within our controller action. Which causing empty result set in `StartProcedure` action.

[image]

How do you fix it:

If order to fix the existing inconsistent code , first of all, I think with can get rid of the script references because scripts are not mandatory what you are trying to achieve.

Then,  we should better  define a tableId so that while we would loop over the table element we can get the tr item by table Id. Finally, we have to use `[FromBody]` with in controller action.

Let's have a look in the modifed code:

View:

```
@model List<ShoppingCartApp.Controllers.MaterialInfo>
<table id="materialTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var material in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => material.isSelected)
                </td>
                <td>@material.Id</td>
                <td>@material.Code</td>
                <td>@material.Name</td>
                <td>@material.Description</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="submitButton">Submit Selected Items</button>
```

Script:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submitButton").click(function () {
                var selectedMaterials = new Array();
                $("#materialTable tbody tr").each(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var isChecked = row.find("td:eq(0) input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked');
                    if (isChecked) {
                        var material = {
                            Id: row.find("td:eq(1)").text(),
                            Code: row.find("td:eq(2)").text(),
                            Name: row.find("td:eq(3)").text(),
                            Description: row.find("td:eq(4)").text()
                        };
                        selectedMaterials.push(material);
                    }
                });
                console.log(selectedMaterials);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/MaterialInfo/StartProcedure",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(selectedMaterials),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (r) {
                        alert(r + " Success.");
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       
                        console.error("Error submitting data:", textStatus, errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List<MaterialInfo> list = new List<MaterialInfo>()
    {
        new MaterialInfo(){isSelected = false, Id = 101, Code = "MAT-001", Name = "MAT-A", Description = "Description-X"},
        new MaterialInfo(){isSelected = true, Id = 102, Code = "MAT-002", Name = "MAT-B", Description = "Description-Y"},
        new MaterialInfo(){isSelected = false, Id = 103, Code = "MAT-003", Name = "MAT-C", Description = "Description-Z"}
    };
    return View(list);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StartProcedure([FromBody] List<MaterialInfo> materials)
{
    try
    {
        //foreach (var item in materials)
        //{

        //}
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Sample Model:

```
public class MaterialInfo
{
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Code { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Output

[image]

**Note:** If you notice,  I have done few refactoring in order to increase readability and tried to reduce code smell. This, how you should troubleshoot your this kind of issue step by step.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your excellent answer and your efforts. There is another important question I want to ask. There are enum types and datetimes in my model, and since it returns json, the expected parameter (List<MaterialInfo> materials) materials is null. If I wait for List<object> materials, the list is returned, but it comes as "ValueKind = object" and I don't know how to make it suitable for my model. I need to return the incoming object objects as a foreach and cast them into my own model. I would be very happy if you could help me with this.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am to glad to assist you on this. Regarding the new question, would be great if you could post another question along with code snippet and the output you are expecting so that this question keep unique.